# Replacing a value in nested map

Tags: scala

I have nested map and i want to replace the values in that map for a specific key. I also want to preserve the nested structure of the map. Here is my attempt to replace the values but it is not working.

```
 def replaceValuesInMap(input:Map[String,Any],inputkey:String,inputValue:String): Map[String, Any] = {
    val output = input.map(x => x match {
      case ((key, value:String)) => {
        if (key == inputkey)
          (key -> inputValue)
        else
          (key -> value)
      }
      case ((_, value: Map[String, Any])) => replaceValuesInMap(value, inputkey, inputValue)
    })
    output.toMap
  }
```

I get the following error:

```
Type mismatch:
Required: Map[String,Any]
Found: Map[Nothing,Nothing]
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Are the values always a `String` or another nested `Map`?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez There is another nested map in it but type of all value and keys is string.

Comment: It is recommended to use a proper data structure then, check this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/ruuCyGDCTPOSANeqchvTxg/5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change this line

```
case ((_, value: Map[String, Any])) => replaceValuesInMap(value, inputkey, inputValue)
```

to

```
case ((key, value: Map[String @unchecked, _ ])) => key -> replaceValuesInMap(value, inputkey, inputValue)
```